# Killed process ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, memory

I ran my script for annotating images before 3 days and when it was finish yesterday, this message shows up `"Killed"`. Why is that?

And when I run `dmesg`, the output is: `[269538.495694] Out of memory: Killed process 10231 (python3) total-vm:5864124kB, anon-rss:4250068kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:8880kB oom_score_adj:0`

I'm using ubuntu 22.04.

The script opens json file on the beggining and inside some function for annotating text on images, the write_json() is called.
And the data (images with text) was read from .h5 file

```
def write_json(data, filename='da.json'):
    with open(filename,'w') as file:
          ujson.dump(data,file,indent=4)
    
with open("da.json") as json_file:
     data=ujson.load(json_file)
     temp=data["annotations"]

def viz_textbb(text_im, imageName, charBB_list, wordBB, textToList, alpha=1.0):
    start = 0
    coordinate = []
    name = []
    upperList = []
    downList = [] 
    FinalFinal = [] 
    imageData = { }
    dictList = []

  for eachWord in textToList:
        length = len(eachWord)
        for i in range(0,4):
            for j in range(start,length+start):
                coordinate.append([charBB_list[0][0][i][j], charBB_list[0][1][i][j]])
            name.append(coordinate)
            coordinate = []

         for j in range(0, length):
            for i in range(len(name)) :
                if(i == 0 or i == 1):
                    upperList.append(name[i][j])
                if(i == 2):
                    downList.append(name[i+1][j])
                if(i == 3):
                    downList.append(name[i-1][j])

         down = reversed(downList)
         joinList = [*upperList,*down,upperList[0]]

         FinalFinal.append(joinList)
        
         imageData['transcription']=eachWord
         imageData['language']="Latin"
         imageData['illegibility']=False
         imageData['points']=joinList
         dictionary_copy = imageData.copy()
         dictList.append(dictionary_copy)

         del(dictionary_copy)

         name=[]
         upperList = []
         downList = []
         start = len(eachWord) + start

  finalDict = {f'gt_{imageName}':dictList}
  
  temp.update(finalDict)
        
  write_json(data)

def main(db_fname):
    db = h5py.File(db_fname, 'r')
    dsets = sorted(db['data'].keys())
    #print ("total number of images : ", colorize(Color.RED, len(dsets), highlight=True))
    for k in dsets:
        rgb = db['data'][k][...]
        charBB = db['data'][k].attrs['charBB']
        wordBB = db['data'][k].attrs['wordBB']
        txt = db['data'][k].attrs['txt']
        textToList = (db['data'][k].attrs['txt']).tolist()
        
        viz_textbb(rgb, k,[charBB], wordBB, textToList)
        
        print ("image name        : ", colorize(Color.RED, k, bold=True))
        # print ("  ** no. of chars : ", colorize(Color.YELLOW, charBB.shape[-1]))
        # print ("  ** no. of words : ", colorize(Color.YELLOW, wordBB.shape[-1]))
        print ("  ** text         : ", colorize(Color.GREEN, txt))
        
    db.close()
json.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main('results/SynthText.h5')
```

Comment: "Why is that, does someone know?" - `Out of memory`, so it's out of memory. Does that answer your question?

Comment: what I need to do? Can I expand memory? Which memory, I have enough space 145gb. I'm new in ubutnu and asking for help.

Comment: Your Python script used 5.8 GB of memory, of which 4.2 GB were in RAM. You could add more hardware, likely RAM. You could also check why your script requires that much memory.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. It will be similar on Windows. You're asking for help? No, you're not. You are asking a why-question and the answer to that it "out of memory". In order to help you, we need much more information, e.g. a [mre]. We don't even know what your script does.

Comment: You can also check for possible memory leaks in the script.

Comment: I updated question with more information, script just finds  bounding boxes coordinates of text instances and paste this coordinates in `json` file. I'm using `ujson` for faster pasting in json.